# Accurately Reading Document Content with Position Using Open XML (Word)

Tags: openxml

I have a need to retrieve a string which matches perfectly the content of a word document. That is to say, in position 1000 of this string, I should find exactly the text at position 1000 in the document.

We have been through various iterations of reading in the document context text and adjusting for field codes/tables/pictures/inline shapes etc by padding in the right places. This approach does work (well) but we want to move towards Open XML instead for speed.

We have Power Tools for Open Xml installed, and have been looking at ways to recreate this string using Open Xml. We can get all the text by going through the runs (as per Eric White's blogs), but we also need everything else. \r's, \t's etc. I see things like "TabChar" in runs, and wdfldChar, but I am unclear how to use this information to generically get what we want.

For example, "TabChar" in our string should be \t. We must need to interpret wdfldChar begin, separate, end in a certain way (maybe by adding spaces). The problem is that we don't want to have to find every possibility and code them

[If run = "TabChar" append."\t" etc] a) because it's inefficient, b) it is unsafe.

Can anyone help with a method to reproduce this string with complete accuracy?

Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to actually represent the question you're asking or the problem you're having. What's there now is nothing that isn't already available in the tags, and it will  have no meaning to a future user who sees it in a search result. Titles should be descriptive in nature, so we have an idea what problem you're having help solving. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I am new. I have changed it. I don't suppose you have any advice on the subject matter? I am finding answers hard to come by.

Comment: Someone must have something..... anything....

Comment: If someone does, they'll answer you. This is not a *give me immediate attention now* site. If you need urgent help, pay a consultant to provide it. Otherwise, be patient - it's only been 4 hours since you posted your question here.

Comment: Thanks for all your help Ken, most helpful and polite, a real advert for this site. I have been trying to find consultants also. My usage of this site is not through a need to save money, merely to try and find someone who can answer the question, who I would be more than willing to pay. Unfortunately it seems in this case help is not forthcoming from any avenue. Thanks again.

Comment: My last comment was addressing your "I don't suppose you have"... followed by "Someone must have something...". It was intended to be helpful - people here don't respond well to impatience and nagging when you're asking them to volunteer their time and effort. Patience is a virtue, particularly here.